# Golang VSCode configuration best setup

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, installation

I wonder if someone can share their best setup for Golang using Vscode on Mac. As I am continously having issues such as:

1. sometimes gomft doesn't work.
2. Functions defined in the same package shows with a red underline warning saying it's not defined (but works when running it)
3. having the following message popped up

`Your workspace is misconfigured: command-line-arguments has no metadata. Please see https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/troubleshooting.md for more information or file an issue (https://github.com/golang/go/issues/new) if you believe this is a mistake.`

Here are some information of my go setup:

- Version: go1.13.4 darwin/amd64
- Settings in 'settings.json':

```
    {
        "window.zoomLevel": 1,
        "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
        "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
        "go.useLanguageServer": true,
        "go.formatTool": "gofmt",
        "go.lintTool": "golangci-lint",
        "[go]": {
            "editor.formatOnSave": true,
            "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
                "source.organizeImports": true
            },
        },
        "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
        "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
        "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false
    }
```

- GOPATH is pointing to the folder where Go is installed

Comment: These kind of problems also happens to me sometimes. Restarted the VS Code solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

you can try this setting.

```
    "go.inferGopath": false,
    "go.buildOnSave": "workspace",
    "go.lintOnSave": "package",
    "go.vetOnSave": "package",
    "go.buildTags": "",
    "go.buildFlags": [],
    "go.lintFlags": [],
    "go.vetFlags": [],
    "go.coverOnSave": false,
    "go.useCodeSnippetsOnFunctionSuggest": false,
    "go.formatTool": "goreturns",
    "go.gocodeAutoBuild": false,
    "go.useLanguageServer": true,
    "go.alternateTools": {
      "go-langserver": "gopls", 
    },
    "go.languageServerExperimentalFeatures": {
      "format": true,
      "autoComplete": true
    },
    "[go]": {
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": true
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

go.useLanguageServer: false, may help you

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for helping others. Your answer could be even more helpful if you add some additional explanation to it.

Comment: It seems to have worked for areas in the code where they are marked as red for. 'not defined'. However as per documentation on language server, it should also bring some benefits, so by disabling it, it might disable some features?  - ```The Language Server protocol is used between a tool (the client) and a language smartness provider (the server) to integrate features like auto complete, go to definition, find all references and alike into the tool```

Comment: Maybe navigating to the definition of a code symbol can't be used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same problem and also using `golangci-lint` for a lint tool.  When I look at the output from the Go extension (View > Command Pallet > Output: Focus on Output View; then choose "Go" in the dropdown for the output view), I see errors like this:

```
Error while running tool: /usr/local/bin/golangci-lint run --print-issued-lines=false
level=warning msg="[runner] Can't run linter goanalysis_metalinter: assign: failed prerequisites: inspect@example.com/pkg/example"
```

And this

```
level=error msg="Running error: buildssa: analysis skipped: errors in package: [/Users/tschaub/projects/pkg/example.go:6:15: undeclared name: SomethingIJustStartedTyping
```

The first error (`assign: failed prerequisites`) was ticketed in https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/issues/827 and closed with a comment about updating to `golangci-lint@v1.24.0`.

The second error (`buildssa: analysis skipped`) was ticketed in https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/issues/896 and is receiving new comments as I type this.

[Upgrading to v1.24.0](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint#install) may not solve the issue, but it sounds like it might generate more descriptive output.

Even using `golangci-lint@v1.24.0` doesn't fix the problem for me.  I need to quit VSCode and restart it whenever I get in this "misconfigured" state.  I'm hoping that after tools catch up with go modules, things will be a bit more stable/reliable.

Comment: I tried to go back to Goland, but just no longer comfortable with that anymore. Will hope they fix that soon.